# What is a possible interface to return for Entity framework entity classes?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have several ef entity classes (generated database 1st). i am limited to using EF 3.5
I need to return a common type from a repository interface  - 
tried to use a custom interface extended in the partial entity classes but didnt work -

some of my code:

Repository interface :

```
interface IRepository
{
     List<string> GetColumnNames();


     IQueryable<EntityObject> GetAll();//what common type/interface can I return here?
}
```

Repository class:
I have several of these

```
class CatalogItemRepository:IRepository
{
    private string repositoryName="CatalogItem";

    public List<string> GetColumnNames()
    {
       //implementation
    }
    public IQueryable<CatalogItem> GetAll()
    {
       //implementation
    }

}
```

Entity classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a generic repository Pattern?

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    List<string> GetColumnNames();

    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}

public class CatalogItemRepository : IRepository<CatalogItem>
{
    private string repositoryName="CatalogItem";

    public List<string> GetColumnNames()
    {
       //implementation
    }

    public IQueryable<CatalogItem> GetAll()
    {
       //implementation
    }
}
```